# SQLite query to extract unique values from json

Tags: database, react-native, sqlite, sqlite-json1

For use in React Native,

Suppose I have a SQLite database table contains col1 primary, col2.

Where col1 contains a serial number and col2 contains a JSON like

```
col1   :    col2
  1    :   {"id":"id1", "value":"value1"}, 
  2    :   {"id":"id2", "value":"value2, value3"}, 
  3    :   {"id":"id3", "value":"value4, value5"}
```

and I just want to extract those unique value using SQLite query,
output I expect is : `["value1","value2","value3","value4","value"]`

Comment: Fetch records as it's ... and normalize them in your js-code...

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli Is there any simple way to extract directly using sqlite query beacuse in my case data could be in a large quantity so it could slows down my project

Comment: forpas nailed it in the answer down below...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `json_extract()`:

```
select group_concat(json_extract(col2, '$.value'), ', ') result
from tablename
```

Result:

```
> result                                
> -------------------------------------
> value1, value2, value3, value4, value5
```

Or if you want the result formatted as a json array use `json_group_array()`:

```
select replace(json_group_array(json_extract(col2, '$.value')), ', ', '","') result
from tablename
```

Result:

```
> | result                                         |
> | :--------------------------------------------- |
> | ["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"] |
```

If you can' use [the JSON1 Extension](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) then you can do it with string functions:

```
select group_concat(substr(
         col2, 
         instr(col2, '"value":"') + length('"value":"'), 
         length(col2) - (instr(col2, '"value":"') + length('"value":"') + 1)
       ), ', ') result
from tablename
```

Result:

```
> result                                
> -------------------------------------
> value1, value2, value3, value4, value5
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=39e2619d7c9a607ec66dd785e560f46d).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but json_extract() method not found in my case

Comment: @Bhupesh check this: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html

Comment: You didn't get me, I asked how to use this query in react native